# Errors installing eclipse on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: eclipse, installation

I'm trying to install Eclipse on my Windows 7 laptop.

When trying to run eclipse.exe I got the following error:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations: C:\ProgramFiles
>   (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe 
>   javaw.exe in your current PATH

I know that I have a JRE on my computer, so I modified the eclipse.ini file to point it to the correct location:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin
```

Now when I run the eclipse exe file it starts to run, but then I get the following error:

> Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll"

I tried adding the javaw.exe file to the path in eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
```

But then I get a long detailed error message:

```
---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 1e38_58
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Any ideas of how I can get Eclipse to run?

Comment: Two things - How did you install Java?, and paste the entire "long detailed error message".

Comment: Why not set right path in PATH variable?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - I didn't install it explicitly, I think it came with the OS. And any tips on how to copy and paste the error message? It doesn't let me right click. Maybe I'll just take a screen shot

Comment: @froadie See if you can copy the error message by pressing Ctrl+C.

Comment: @EliAcherkan - thanks! didn't realize that would work with nothing selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you're version of Eclipse and JDK match, either both 64-bit or both 32-bit, then set the path of the JRE in the .ini file .

I think that the problem in your case is that you have a 64bit version of eclipse and you are trying to run it with a 32bit JVM ...

Comment: I have a 64-bit OS, so I installed the 64-bit version of eclipse. Why would I have a 32-bit JRE? And how can I check?

Comment: No, in this case you should have a 64bit version of Java(but now you have installed a 32bit version as stated by log), Remove the installed version and install a 64bit JRE ...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've installed a 64-Bit version of Java and your eclipse.ini points to this Java version.

See http://blog.janjonas.net/2013-02-09/eclipse-windows-64bit-java-runtime-environment-java-development-kit-must-be-available-java-returned-exit-code-13 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a common issue**, check *i)* which version of Java do you have (`java -version`), and *ii)* also check you are using x64 JRE with an installation of x64 Eclipse (or x86 from both of them).

Also, specifying the `-vm` is important to be well-formed: you should specify the full path for the `javaw.exe` file. For the details, refer to the [documentation of the eclipse.ini file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Windows_Example).

Comment: @aleroot Negative, it matters in the sense that it does print if it is a 64-Bit or a 32-Bit installation. I believe this is vital in the current issue because I suspect there is a x86 JRE and an x64 Eclipse installation, which are, incompatible, and gives exactly the same error message on startup.

Comment: Yes, and what is said in my answer ? I think this too ... It is not important the version but the arch ...

Answer (score 0):

for this problem  you have to install first latest version java and install
 eclipse workbench :https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R2/eclipse-inst-win64.exe&mirror_id=105 . select eclipse ide and start install